# How to get live stream of twitter with multiple hashtags

Tags: twitter, real-time, twitter4j, hashtag

I want to listen to real time all the tweets which has #abc #def hashtags for example,

preferred language is Java but raw API is great too

I couldn't find the documentation that describes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with twitter4j, but what you'll need to utilize their [Streaming API](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#streaming) example.

From that you'll need to include [filter](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html#filter-twitter4j.FilterQuery-) method.

A more detailed example is found in this [example](http://davidcrowley.me/?p=435)

```
    FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

    String keywords[] = {"ireland"};

    fq.track(keywords);
```

Comment: do you happen to know the same API for instagram ?

Comment: Glad that worked for you. As for Instagram, I'm sorry I'm not very familiar with their API. Hopefully [jInstagram](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram/wiki/Instagram-Realtime-API) might get you started